# SUM function not recognized

Tags: android, sqlite, calllog

i'm trying to build a query wich retreives the sum of incoming calls duration.
The problem is that SUM() is not recognized.
The error Message is `Invalid Column SUM(DURATION)`.
Thank you.
This is my code :

```
    String[] columns = {"SUM("+CallLog.Calls.DURATION+")"};
    String selection = CallLog.Calls.DATE+" >= ? and "+CallLog.Calls.TYPE+" =    "+CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE;
    String[] args = { String.valueOf(lastMonthMillis) };

    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, columns,
            selection, args, CallLog.Calls.DATE);
```

I tried it like this :

```
String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
            CallLog.Calls.DATE, "SUM(" + CallLog.Calls.DURATION + ")" };
    String selection = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + " = ? and "
            + CallLog.Calls.DATE + " >= ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE),
            String.valueOf(lastMonthMillis) };
    String sortOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE+" DESC";
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection,   selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

The error is `Invalid Column SUM(DURATION)` so duration is recognized ?
Any suggestion ?

Comment: It's the column that's not recognized, not the sum function. Did you add that column to your projection map?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do that. You can find a lot of questions on this if you Google "Android Invalid Column." I linked to one with a detailed answer above.

Comment: But how to get an SQLITEDataBase Object from an already existing Content Provider ?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495657/am-i-able-to-run-sql-functions-on-a-contentresolver-columns-query